# How can I add drop down Sub menu code to this menu

Tags: html, wordpress

This is the html code of my menu. I would like to add the page "Inspection" as a dropdown sub menu of the page "Services". Could you please help me how can I add dropdown sub menu code to the "Our Services"?

```
          <nav class="main-navigation">                      
              
            <ul>
              <li <?php if (is_page('about-us') or wp_get_post_parent_id(0) == 117) echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/about-us') ?>">About Us</a></li>
              <li <?php if (is_page('our-services') or wp_get_post_parent_id(0) == 266) echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/our-services') ?>">Our Services</a>
                <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="<?php echo site_url('/our-services/inspection') ?>">Inspection</a></li>
        </ul>
                </li>
                
              <li <?php if (get_post_type() == 'trainingcourses') echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/trainingcourses') ?>">Training Courses</a></li>
              <li <?php if (is_page('our-career') or wp_get_post_parent_id(0) == 141) echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/our-career') ?>">Career</a></li>
              <li <?php if (is_page('contact') or wp_get_post_parent_id(0) == 144) echo 'class="current-menu-item"' ?>><a href="<?php echo site_url('/contact') ?>">Contact Us</a></li>
            </ul>
              
          </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

set the "our services" `postion:"realtive"` and the submenu `position: "absolute"` in css. Then set `the display:"none"` of submenu. Once the user hovers or clicks the "our services" element then the menu will have `display:"block"`. i.e. add a pseudo class hover or focus as per your choice and set the submenu div to `display : "block"`. I am also adding the doc link for further reference `https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. I added these codes to the "site-header.css" file. But it doesn't work. Could you please check it out?
this is also the URL of my website: https://itnog.de/

Comment: &__submenu {
    visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
    display: block;
  }

      &__our services {
    visibility: hidden;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
  }

Comment: remove the visibility property as we are using display that will fix your code and then you can align your submenu using left right top and bottom css property.

Comment: have a glance at properties like position, display and visibility from MDN. its a basic thing you will understand once you look at the DOCS.